# Power shell script for blocking an Active Directory user account if the password is not changed within 24 hours

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is it possible to block a user account if the user does not change his password after 24 hours from the moment the administrator restarts the user's password?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is not bulletproof as it relies on the whenChanged attribute that might be changed by any other reason (something else changed on the object).

It is a PowerShell script that could be executed multiple times a day to be close to the 24 hours password change timeframe.
It will get all *enabled* users wich *have to change their password* and where the user object has not been modified within 1 day.

```
$MaxLastChanged = $(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$Filter = { (pwdLastSet -eq 0) -and (enabled -eq "true") -and (whencreated -lt $MaxLastChanged) }
$AllUsersToGetDisabled = Get-ADUser -Filter $Filter -Properties WhenCreated

foreach ($User in $AllUsersToGetDisabled) {
    Disable-ADAccount $User
}
```

Create a scheduled task for it and you will be fine.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, thank you very much :)

Comment: If it helps/works for you then you might upvote/select as answer. As described here https://stackoverflow.com/tour